# Disabling keyboard use for input range

Tags: javascript, html

I have a standard form with a slider:

```
`<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" id="my_slider" name="my_slider">`
```

The value of the slider can be selected either with the mouse or with the arrow keys (after clicking on the slider). How can I disable the keyboard and force the user to position the slider with the mouse?

One possibility is obviously to disable the arrow keys on the whole page with Java Script, but  I would like to avoid that if possible.

Thank you.

Comment: And what about people that are not able to use a mouse? What is the real issue you are trying to solve by blocking arrow keys? Seems like when people ask questions like htis, they are trying to mask another problem.

Comment: @epascarello I am programming a lab experiment for which participation requires being able to use a mouse (for other tasks).

Comment: @epascarello I understand that this request is strange but I have good scientific reasons to block the arrow keys (I could give more details but it would rather distract from my question).

Comment: You really shouldn't disable keyboard events. A proper website should allow anything that can be done via mouse to also be doable via keyboard. If you insist you could `$(''#some_id').keydown(false);`

Comment: So bind a keydown listener and block it....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can block the keys with onkeydown event...

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" id="my_slider" name="my_slider"
 onkeydown="event.preventDefault()">
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a key listener to the input and call [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) on the event which will cancel it, preventing the default action from being triggered:

```js
var mySlider = document.getElementById("my_slider");

mySlider.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" id="my_slider" name="my_slider">
```